# Why I can't build hibernate-orm from source code?

Tags: java, hibernate, intellij-idea

Following the Quickstart of the ReadMe file of [Hibernate](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm) library,

I came across the following problem when trying to run this piece of code:

`./gradlew clean build`

org.hibernate.test.type.TimeAndTimestampTest > test FAILED
    java.lang.AssertionError at TimeAndTimestampTest.java:47

org.hibernate.test.timestamp.JdbcTimeDefaultTimeZoneTest > testTimeZone FAILED
    java.lang.AssertionError at JdbcTimeDefaultTimeZoneTest.java:83

5335 tests completed, 2 failed, 209 skipped
:hibernate-core:test FAILED
:hibernate-core:buildDashboard

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':hibernate-core:test'.

  > A build operation failed.
  >     Could not write XML test results for org.hibernate.test.annotations.derivedidentities.e3.b3.DerivedIdentityEmbeddedIdParentEmbeddedIdGrandparentEmbeddedIdColumnOverridesDepTest to file /home/liver/Documents/repos/hibernate-orm/hibernate-core/target/test-results/TEST-org.hibernate.test.annotations.derivedidentities.e3.b3.DerivedIdentityEmbeddedIdParentEmbeddedIdGrandparentEmbeddedIdColumnOverridesDepTest.xml.

To build the project I used this workaround:

```
./gradlew build -x test
```

However, this isn't appropiate since it skips all the tests while building.

When I try to run that specific test *TimeAndTimestampTest.java* on IntelliJ I get the following:
[Screenshot of the failed test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zAHZN.png)

Apparently,the source code doesn't recognize the following route to import the missing libraries:

```
org.hibernate.jpamodelgen.xml.jaxb.*
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Maybe you have some configuration problem which is preventing Hiberbate from operating normally.

Comment: Are you try to build the master branch or one its tagged releases?

Comment: @Powerlord I'm using the master branch.